# Airflow pythonOperator ds variable within function

Tags: python, jinja2, amazon-redshift, airflow

I know that the question has been asked before but none of the answers have answered it. I'm beginning to go slightly crazy! **I'm very confused so would really appreciate some help.**

I've got a DAG with a python operator which runs a SQL query and outputs to .csv. A second operator just returns true in order to make a DAG. I can't seem to access the ds variable within my function. I want to do this in order to pass to the query.

```
from airflow.models import Variable, DAG
from airflow.hooks import HttpHook, PostgresHook
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json


sql_path = Variable.get("sql_path")
date = Variable.get("ds")
first_date = Variable.get("ds")

print date

def get_redshift_data(ds,**kwargs):
    pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='redshift')
    params = {'window_start_date':date,'window_end_date':first_date}
    with open(sql_path+"/native.sql") as f:
        sql_file = f.read() % (params)
    df2 = pg_hook.get_pandas_df(sql_file)
    df2.to_csv("test_1.csv", encoding = "utf-8")

def print_test(ds, **kwargs):
    return True

args = {
    'owner': 'Bob',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.utcnow(),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

#Define DAG
dag = DAG(dag_id='native_etl',
          default_args=args,
          schedule_interval='0 * * * 1,2,3,4,5',
          dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=30))

#Task 1 run native query with date parameters and output to file


get_redshift_native = PythonOperator(
                      task_id='native_etl',
                      provide_context=True,
                      python_callable=get_redshift_data,
                      dag=dag
                      )

#Task 2 print test

get_test = PythonOperator(
                      task_id='native_test',
                      provide_context=True,
                      python_callable=print_test,
                      dag=dag
)

get_redshift_native >> get_test

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

When I look at the logs I get the following,

```
raise KeyError('Variable {} does not exist'.format(key))`
```

**I've also tried to access the variable via kwargs["ds"] and {{ ds }} within and outside of the operator.**

The query is fine and contains the templated text:

```
WHERE trunc(pd.server_timestamp) between '%(window_start_date)s' AND '%(window_end_date)s'
```

Comment: Use this approach to push the context into the Operator and you are done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093718/airflow-python-script-with-execution-date-in-op-kwargs/50095130#50095130

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use a `template_dict` to pass in the `ds` template in your PythonOperator.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L56

For example, if I wanted to pass `execution_date` to a PythonOperator:

```
def transform_py(**kwargs):

    today = kwargs.get('templates_dict').get('today', None)
    ...

with dag:

    today = "{{ ds_nodash }}"

    transform = PythonOperator(
            task_id='test_date',
            python_callable=transform_py,
            templates_dict={
                'today': today,

            },
            provide_context=True)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This helped me understand where I was going wrong.  In the end I used the solution outlined by @WillFitzgerald here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41749974/airflow-using-template-files-for-pythonoperatorIt really isn't very clear in what context the variables are available and that some operators can access the variables readily (postgresOperator) whereas others cannot as in this case.