# Airflow PythonOperator template_dict raises error TemplateNotFound(template)

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm trying to pass `bar.sql` through the PythonOperator's template_dict for use in the python_callable, like the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.PythonOperator) mention, but [this is the closest example I've found](https://marclamberti.com/blog/templates-macros-apache-airflow/). I've also reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41749974/airflow-using-template-files-for-pythonoperator/50200923#50200923) which references Airflow 1.8, but the solution did not work for me in practice - I'm using Airflow 2.2.4.

(Also, there seems to be a well known BashOperator issue ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147514/templatenotfound-error-when-running-simple-airflow-bashoperator) and [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147514/templatenotfound-error-when-running-simple-airflow-bashoperator) references) where TemplateNotFound errors are common. For the BashOperator, you can troubleshoot by changing `command='script.sh'` to `command='script.sh '`, but I did not have any such luck using this with my .sql file passed to PythonOperator's template_dict.)

My task below is resulting in the logs raising an error `TemplateNotFound(template): bar.sql`

```py
with DAG(
    'bigquery-dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    template_searchpath=['usr/local/airflow/include']
) as dag:

    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start',
        on_success_callback=some_other_function
    )

    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='sql_printer',
        python_callable=sqlPrinter,
        templates_dict={'sql': 'bar.sql'},
        templates_exts=['.sql',],
        provide_context=True
    )

    start >> t1
```

**My goal is for `bar.sql` to be available for use in `sqlPrinter`**

```sql
-- ~/include/bar.sql
select 'hello world'
```

```py
def sqlPrinter(**context):
    print(f"sql: {context['templates_dict']['sql']}")
```

**The result I would like to see is**

```
>>> sql: select 'hello world'
```

Below is the DAG and error log from `sql_printer` the log results.
[image: dag]

```
[2022-04-04, 22:32:29 ] {taskinstance.py:1264} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): sql_printer> on 2022-04-05 03:32:27.076984+00:00
[2022-04-04, 22:32:29 ] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 15289 to run task
[2022-04-04, 22:32:29 ] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'bigquery-dag', 'sql_printer', 'manual__2022-04-05T03:32:27.076984+00:00', '--job-id', '456', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/bigquery-dag.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp0fjl_t2a', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpuy00moli']
[2022-04-04, 22:32:29 ] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 456: Subtask sql_printer
[2022-04-04, 22:32:29 ] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: bigquery-dag.sql_printer manual__2022-04-05T03:32:27.076984+00:00 [running]> on host 1296ec2abf88
[2022-04-04, 22:32:30 ] {taskinstance.py:1718} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1334, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1423, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    self.render_templates(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2011, in render_templates
    self.task.render_template_fields(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1061, in render_template_fields
    self._do_render_template_fields(self, self.template_fields, context, jinja_env, set())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1074, in _do_render_template_fields
    rendered_content = self.render_template(content, context, jinja_env, seen_oids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1131, in render_template
    return {key: self.render_template(value, context, jinja_env) for key, value in content.items()}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1131, in <dictcomp>
    return {key: self.render_template(value, context, jinja_env) for key, value in content.items()}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1108, in render_template
    template = jinja_env.get_template(content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 997, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 958, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 125, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 214, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: bar.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use templates_dict={'**query**': 'bar.sql'}

```
t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='sql_printer',
        python_callable=sqlPrinter,
        templates_dict={'query': 'bar.sql'},
        provide_context=True
    )
def sqlPrinter(**context):
    print(f"sql: {context['templates_dict']['query']}")
```

the idea is came from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45887539/9460345)

Comment: This also resulted in TemplateNotFound. Does `templates_dict={'query': 'bar.sql'}` work for you?